# Passing function with a parameter as a parameter to another function

Tags: jquery

Why does this error (`jquery-1.7.1.js:3256 Uncaught TypeError: Object 50 has no method 'apply' Uncaught TypeError: Object 50 has no method 'apply'`):

```
var func = function(foo) {
  // some code
});

$('.some_class').keyup(func('bar'));
```

Many thanks :).

Comment: Because `func('bar')` probably returns `undefined`. You have to pass a function to `keyup`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Trying to pass in a callback function fails](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6811746/trying-to-pass-in-a-callback-function-fails)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're passing the result of `fun` as the callback to be invoked. You want to send the function itself. Do this by wrapping it in an anonymous function:

```
$('.some_class').keyup(function(){
 func('bar');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Pass `func` alone: `func('bar')` is invoking the function and passing its result to `.keyup`.

(You also have an extra `)` in your assignment to `func`)

Answer (score 0):

Wrap it in an anonymous function:

```
$('.some_class').keyup(function () {
    func('bar');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

when you do

```
$('.some_class').keyup(func('bar'));
```

It effectively means the return value of `func` is the argument to `keyup`.

So, if your function is like this

```
func(foo) { return 5; }
```

Its the same as

```
$('.some_class').keyup(5);
```

Use an anonymous function

```
$('.some_class').keyup(function(){func('bar');});
```